# Aborting zsh command, leaving it visible

Tags: zsh

Sometimes, after having found a command from history with `ctrl-r`, I would like it to remain on the terminal without executing it.  This is achieved by `ctrl-c` in bash, but not in zsh.  Is there a way?

Comment: Can you use the arrow keys to navigate through the currently selected one?

Comment: @Joe, yes, it seems that `c-f c-c` will do.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, without `c-f` first the command disappears.

Comment: Ah sorry, I get it, you're still at the incremental search prompt when you press ^C, so yes, you'd need to leave that first and ctrl-f will do.

Answer (score 0):

After finding the line you want with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, just press <kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>→</kbd> or even just start editing the line to leave the search.

Answer (score -1):

One way to do this would be to use the arrow keys to navigate forwards/backwards through the history entry you want to remain.